# How to call php file within the windows phone 8 application?

Tags: php, authentication, windows-phone-8

I want to create log in process in windows phone using MySQL with php.

below is my code for access database it's not working.

**XAML CODE**

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(System.Object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "http://localhost/check_login/check.php";
            //string url = "http://localhost/sam.php";
            Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);

            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "sUsername", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "sPassword", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.txtPassword.Password.ToString()));

            WebClient client = default(WebClient);
            client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();

            client.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadStringCompleted;
            client.UploadProgressChanged += client_UploadProgressChanged;

            client.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        prog = new ProgressIndicator();
        prog.IsIndeterminate = true;
        prog.IsVisible = true;
        prog.Text = "Loading....";
        SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, prog);

    }
```

**PHP CODE**

```
    <?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("login_db");

//$_POST["sUsername"] = "weerachai"; // for Sample
//$_POST["sPassword"] = "weerachai@1";  // for Sample

$strUsername = $_POST["sUsername"];
$strPassword = $_POST["sPassword"];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE 1 
    AND Username = '".$strUsername."'  
    AND Password = '".$strPassword."'  
    ";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
$intNumRows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);
if($intNumRows==0)
{
    echo "0|0|Incorrect Username and Password";
}
else
{
    echo "1|".$objResult["MemberID"]."|"."Valid User121";
}

/**
return 
x|y|z
    x // (0=Failed , 1=Complete)
    y // MemberID
    z // Error Message
*/

mysql_close($objConnect);

    ?>
```

I don't know add anything additional to run that file in emulator.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you're trying to connect to "localhost" from the emulator.

The WP8 emulator is a separate virtual machine. Because of this it thinks of localhost as itself. If you're hosting the PHP script on your development machine you should refer to it from the emulator by hostname or IP address.